# Java compareTo issue

Tags: java

```
int Area() {

            int area=iX1*iY1;
            return area;
        }

        int compareTo(Object r) {


            if(r==area) {

                return 0;
            }

            if (r>area) {

                return 1;
            }
            else {

                return -1;
            }

        }
```

int iX1 and iY1 are just some variable that declare at the beginning of the program. I have to compare `int area` with the submitted as parameter `r`. The issue I get is that `area` cannot be compared to `r`

Comment: You cannot perform arithmetic operations on `Object`s.

Comment: so how am I suppose to compare them

Comment: You need "Head first core java" book to read.

Comment: well area is integer as for r, I guess its integer as well but i haven't declare it anywhere. Sry im kinda new to Java

Answer (score 1):

You are using `==` while comparing objects. Operator `==` compares references, so the result may be true only if both references refer to *the same* object. You probably should invoke `equals()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If Object is some kind of class you want to define, make it has a value which can be compared with interger, if it is really the Class "Object" of Java, there is no way to make such a comparation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare int value to object. You need to cast r to Area and then compare area fields

```
Area areaObject = (Area)r;
if(areaObject.area == this.area) {
     return 0
}
```

There are other problems with this code. Declaration of class cannot look like this you rather should write

```
class Area {
    private int area;
    public Area(int x, int y) {
         area = x * y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object is an Integer object, then you can do this: Now you can compare.

```
int newR = ((Integer) r).intValue();

int compareTo(Object r) {


        if(newR==area) {

            return 0;
        }

        if (newR>area) {

            return 1;
        }
        else {

            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code fragment looks like you want to implement a class, lets name it `YourType`, where two instances can be ordered by comparing a computed value (the area). The typical way is to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
class YourType implements Comparable<YourType> {

  private int iX1, iY1;

  ...

  int Area() {
    return iX1*iY1;
  }

  int compareTo(YourType other) {
    int myArea = Area();
    int otherArea = other.Area();
    if (otherArea == area) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (otherArea > area) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

The compareTo() method is designed to compare two objects of the same type (or supertype) not apples with pears. If you miss the generic parameter, the compiler would assume Object as type to compare which is mostly useless.

The most simple implementation would be:

```
  int compareTo(YourType other) {
    return Integer.valueOf(Area()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(other.Area()));
  }
```